# Where can i find a list of all the window manager protocol atoms?

Tags: python, tkinter, protocols, window-managers

Where can i find a list of all the window manager protocol atoms?

I have these few:

- WM_DELETE_WINDOW
- WM_SAVE_YOURSELF
- WM_TAKE_FOCUS

They are commonly used when incepting window manager events in Python's Tkinter in the style of:

```
widget.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", handler)
```

Where can i get a complete list of these?

Comment: http://standards.freedesktop.org/wm-spec/wm-spec-1.3.html

Comment: Are you wanting all atoms, or only the ones that work in Tkinter?

Comment: Only the ones that work in Tkinter.

Answer (score 1):

See [Extended Window Manager Hints](http://standards.freedesktop.org/wm-spec/wm-spec-latest.html).

(based on [Andrey Sidorov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/705115/andrey-sidorov)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22595515/where-can-i-find-a-list-of-all-the-window-manager-protocol-atoms#comment34410310_22595515))

Comment: This isn't complete – it doesn't, for instance, have `WM_SAVE_YOURSELF`. Also, this is a link-only answer.