# Is there a way to resize the children widgets when the parent widget is maximized in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk

I'm currently working on this project and was wondering is there a way to resize all the children widgets present inside the parent widget when the user maximize the parent widget `root`, I know about `.grid_rowconfigure()`and `.grid_columnconfigure()`, but using these methods isn't changing the fontsize/actual size of my widgets.
I would like to know if there's a way to bind the maximize button
present on the top right conner of the parent widget.

**Thank you.**

Comment: how did you try to do that, please provide a [mre]

Comment: Does this help? [Where can i find a list of all the window manager protocol atoms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22595515/where-can-i-find-a-list-of-all-the-window-manager-protocol-atoms?r=SearchResults&s=1|62.9851). This should let you know whether there's a way to bind the maximize button.

Comment: Yes, there are ways using every one of the geometry managers. They all have options that control how the widgets are resized. Please provide a [mcve] that we can use to reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57533458/detect-if-user-has-clicked-the-maximized-button). The solution: First of all, we need to bind the window to the `<Configure>` event. The `<Configure>` event gets triggered whenever a window event occurs.

```
window.bind("<Configure>", is_maximized)
```

Now, when the event gets triggered, the is_maximized function will be called:

```
def is_maximized(event):
    if window.state() == "zoomed":
        # your code
```

In the function, we are checking if the window state is equal to `zoomed`. If so, it means that the window is maximized. Now, you can just add whatever code you need inside the `if` clause.

Comment: You don't need to do any of this under normal circumstances. Widgets can easily be configure to grow or shrink with the window grows or shrinks.

Comment: @BryanOakley, thanks for pointing it out. I am aware of that. That's just what he asked for.

Comment: Thank you mate, I figured it out. Thanks for the help, really much appreciated.

Comment: @Amaan, if my answer helped you, I’d really appreciate it if you’d upvote or accept the answer

Comment: I would but it's says I need 15 reputation to upvote.

Comment: @Amaan, you can accept the answer. It doesn't require a specific amount of reputation.